# Difference between a "function rule" and a "function property", and the implications on "function uniqueness".

Tags: functions

A lot of the exercises I have recently practiced relate to demonstrating whether or not a function *exists*, and, if it does exist, whether or not it is *unique*. I've developed the pattern-esque rhythm of completing these sorts of proof problems, but I still don't believe I know for certain what exactly is going on.

I've identified two different *parts* to these types of problems (please excuse the informal terminology that follows):

1. you are given a "**function property**"
2. from this "function property", you need to come up with a "**function rule**".

The way I see it, the "function rule" is what is used to generate the set of all possible ordered pairs that ultimately represent "**the function**". If this is the *correct* "function rule", then there will necessarily be a **subset** of ordered pairs (taken from the overarching set that represents "the function") that satisfies the "function property".

---

Now assuming these informal understandings are correct, this makes me wonder what it means for a function to be "unique" versus "non-unique". Firstly, it seems that the idea of uniqueness and non-uniqueness can only be invoked with respect to a particular property (i.e. "a function is unique" is an invalid statement...the proper statement is "a function with a particular property is unique").

Secondly, if a function with a particular property is non-unique, that means that there are other functions that can "**capture the same subset of ordered pairs required to satisfy the " function property"** ", but they use a different "function rule" to do so (and therefore these *different functions* have fundamentally different overarching sets).

Comparatively, if a function with a particular property is unique, that means that there are no other functions that can capture the subset of ordered pairs that satisfy the "function property" without going through one and only one function rule to do so.

Is this the right idea? Any clarity is greatly appreciated!

---

**Edit**: Perhaps an example will be helpful in order to understand my above thoughts...

Consider the following theorem:

> Let $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ be a basis of $V$ and $(w_1, ..., w_n)$ be an arbitrary list of vectors in $W$. Then there exists a unique linear map
> $$T: V \to W\  \text{such that}\  T(v_i) = w_i, \forall i = 1,2, ..., n$$

In this proof:

- the "function property" is $T(v_i) = w_i, \forall i = 1,2, ..., n$
- the resulting "function rule" (which you must generate) is $T(v)=a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n$ where $v$ is any arbitrary vector in $V$, recalling that $v$ can be written as $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$

By plugging $v_1$ into our function (linear map) T, recognizing first that $v_1 = \alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_nv_n$ where all coefficients are $0$ except for $\alpha_1 = 1$, we see that $T(v_1)=w_1$. This can be repeated for all basis vectors of $V$. Thus, we see that **a subset of ordered pairs of the function T** satisfy the property $T(v_i)=w_i$.

Comment: A function is just a set of ordered pairs with a specific property about "preimages".  But yes, that set can be specified in more than one way.